# Unable to get hidden JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

[image]I use a JTable with two buttons(Active & Inactive Buttons) . When I click on the Inactive button I hide the first column of the table. Also I try to show the first column when I click on the Active button. But the problem is , when I click on the Active button I couldn't display the first column with its preferred size .

This is the code for hide the first column,

```
expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(0);
```

This is the code for get back fist column,

```
expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(300);
expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(100);
```

First I click on the Inactive button and then I click on the Active button . But this is not working .

Have any idea to how to do above .

```
private void inactiveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                                   
     expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
     expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
     expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(0);
  }


private void activeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
    {                                                 
        expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
        expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(300);
        expTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(100);
    }
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Normally when I've done this kind of thing in the past, I simply grab a reference to the `TableColumn` and remove it from the `ColumnModel` and add it back in again when needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer :- Can you provide me an example ? I am working on a massive swing project so that's why I couldn't publish any code in it .

Comment: `I am working on a massive swing project so that's why I couldn't publish any code in it .` - you were not asked for your entire project. All you need to do is post a demo of what you are trying to accomplish. That is you create a JFrame with a JTable. Then you create a "Remove Column" button and an "Restore Colum" button. The whole code will be about 20 - 30 lines of code. Learn how to simplify your problems when you ask a question.

Comment: @camickr : Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past when I've need to do something like, I've simply removed and re-added the `TableColumn`

This is a pretty crude example of the concept...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.addColumn("Column 1");
            model.addColumn("Column 2");
            model.addColumn("Column 3");
            model.addColumn("Column 4");
            model.setRowCount(100);

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JToggleButton toggle = new JToggleButton("Toggle");
            toggle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                private TableColumn column;
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
                    if (toggle.isSelected()) {
                        column = columnModel.getColumn(0);
                        table.getColumnModel().removeColumn(column);
                    } else if (column != null) {
                        columnModel.addColumn(column);
                        columnModel.moveColumn(columnModel.getColumnCount() - 1, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
            add(toggle, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }
}
```

I actually spent sometime putting together a custom `TableModel` which provide the ability to hide and show columns, which basically wrapped this functionality up in a nice reusable package

Comment: Can I this use for a table which is in DefaultTableModel ? And can I use a JButton instead of a JToogleButton ?

Comment: I did it but there is an exception .                                                                                                                                                               Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object is null at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.addColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:117)

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: private void inactiveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){new Runnable() {  Override public void run() { // Database caller SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // load data from database to table TableColumn column;TableColumnModel model = pTable.getColumnModel(); Override public void run() {
if (inactiveButton.isSelected()) {column = model.getColumn(0);                          expTable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(column); } else{
model.addColumn(column);                     model.moveColumn(model.getColumnCount() -1,0); }} });}}.run();
}

Comment: Please extract this .

Comment: I couldn't tell that I am using NetBeans IDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97466/discussion-between-barrier-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 5):

Don't attempt to "hide" a `TableColumn` by playing with the width. The `TableColumn` is still part of the table so when the user tabs from column to column, focus will go to the hidden column and disappear from the users view which is very confusing.

Instead you should remove the `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel`. Then you can add the `TableColumn` back to the `TableColumnModel` when needed.

Check out the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/) which manages this concept for you. If you don't use the full functionality of the class you can use the `hideColumn(...)` and `showColumn(...)` to do a simple toggle on the first column.